# Process uploaded file in Wordpress plugin development

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building my first WP plugin. Basically I should upload a CSV file and then read it values to store in a table at Wordpress DB. After read a lot of docs I follow this steps:

- Create two files `frequent-traveler.php` where all the logic resides and `ft_admin.php` where the view part is.
- This is the code I have in `frequent-traveler.php`:

---

```
// Create database tables and some others
function frequent_traveler_activation()
{

}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'frequent_traveler_activation');

// Deletes database tables and some others
function frequent_traveler_deactivation()
{

}

register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'frequent_traveler_deactivation');

function frequent_traveler_admin_actions()
{
    add_options_page("Frequent Traveler Configuration", "Frequent Traveler Config", 'manage_options', "ftconfig", "frequent_traveler_admin");
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'frequent_traveler_admin_actions');

function frequent_traveler_admin()
{
    include('ft_admin.php');
}

if (!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['uploadfile_btn']) && check_admin_referer('name_of_my_action', 'wpnf_ft')) {
    echo "entre";
}
else {
    echo "Error";
}
```

---

- And this is the code at `ft_admin.php`:

---

```
<?php
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
wp_enqueue_style('jquery-style', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');

?>

<div class="wrap">
    <?php echo "<h2>" . __('Frequent Traveler Configuration') . "</h2>"; ?>
    <form name="frequent_traveler_form" method="post" action="<?php echo str_replace('%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="frequent_traveler_hidden" value="Y">
        <?php echo "<h4>" . __('Common Settings') . "</h4>"; ?>
        <p>
            <?php _e("Default Conversion Value: "); ?><input type="text" name="ft_default" value="<?php echo $ft_default; ?>" size="5"> 
            <?php _e("From Date: "); ?><input type="text" id="frequent_traveler_from_date" name="frequent_traveler_from_date" value="<?php echo $frequent_traveler_from_date ?>" class="datepicker" />
            <?php _e("To Date: "); ?><input type="text" id="frequent_traveler_to_date" name="frequent_traveler_to_date" value="<?php echo $frequent_traveler_to_date; ?>" class="datepicker" />
        </p>
        <input type="submit" class="button-primary" name="Submit" value="<?php _e('Save Values') ?>" />
    </form>
    <hr/>
    <?php ?>
    <h2><?php echo __('Upload file to import') ?></h2>
    <form name="uploadfile" id="uploadfile_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo str_replace('%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) . '/uploadfile'; ?>" accept-charset="utf-8" >
        <?php wp_nonce_field('name_of_my_action', 'wpnf_ft'); ?>
        <p><?php echo __('Select file to upload') ?><input type="file" name="uploadfiles[]" id="uploadfiles" size="35" class="uploadfiles" /><p>
            <input class="button-primary" type="submit" name="uploadfile_btn" id="uploadfile_btn" value="<?php echo __('Upload & Process') ?>"  />
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.datepicker').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

As you may notice I'm trying to validate the uploaded file with this code:

```
if (!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['uploadfile_btn']) && check_admin_referer('name_of_my_action', 'wpnf_ft')) {
    echo "entre";
}
else {
    echo "Error";
}
```

But I get always **Error**, why is that? What I'm doing wrong? Which is the best way to handle uploaded files?

Comment: Did you try submit the form? If you don't submit the form it will always show you the `Error` text.

Comment: @RahilWazir yes I submitted the form but then I get a blank page and my URL looks like `wp-admin/options-general.php?page=ftconfig/uploadfile` where is failing?

Comment: Wordpress don't support that url path. It is invalid. Try to process the form in the same page with `action=""`.

Comment: @RahilWazir I'll like to mantain PHP logic code separate from the view (the view has PHP code), is that possible? Lets say I wan to process the form submission at `frequent-traveler.php` file, how?

Comment: Then go ahead process over there. If you done redirect back to `options-general.php` for success and error messages.

Comment: @RahilWazir I get lost, could you help me with some example code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not leave the check for `if (!empty($_POST)` outside any function, it can go inside the `admin_menu` output.

Also, the `form` actions should be left empty, so it posts to the same plugin page.

The targeted enqueue can be done in a standard way too and note the shortcut for jQuery `$`:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'frequent_traveler_admin_actions' );
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_enqueue' );

function frequent_traveler_admin_actions()
{
    $my_hook = add_options_page("Frequent Traveler Configuration", "Frequent Traveler Config", 'manage_options', "ftconfig", "frequent_traveler_admin");
    //var_dump($my_hook); die();
}

function admin_enqueue( $hook )
{
    if( 'settings_page_ftconfig' !== $hook )
        return;

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-style', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
}

function frequent_traveler_admin()
{
    if (!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['uploadfile_btn']) && check_admin_referer('name_of_my_action', 'wpnf_ft')) {
        echo "<h1>entre</h1>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
    }

    $ft_default = '';
    $frequent_traveler_from_date = '';
    $frequent_traveler_to_date = '';
    ?>

    <div class="wrap">
        <?php echo "<h2>" . __('Frequent Traveler Configuration') . "</h2>"; ?>
        <form name="frequent_traveler_form" method="post" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="frequent_traveler_hidden" value="Y">
            <?php echo "<h4>" . __('Common Settings') . "</h4>"; ?>
            <p>
                <?php _e("Default Conversion Value: "); ?><input type="text" name="ft_default" value="<?php echo $ft_default; ?>" size="5"> 
                <?php _e("From Date: "); ?><input type="text" id="frequent_traveler_from_date" name="frequent_traveler_from_date" value="<?php echo $frequent_traveler_from_date ?>" class="datepicker" />
                <?php _e("To Date: "); ?><input type="text" id="frequent_traveler_to_date" name="frequent_traveler_to_date" value="<?php echo $frequent_traveler_to_date; ?>" class="datepicker" />
            </p>
            <input type="submit" class="button-primary" name="Submit" value="<?php _e('Save Values') ?>" />
        </form>
        <hr/>
        <?php ?>
        <h2><?php echo __('Upload file to import') ?></h2>
        <form name="uploadfile" id="uploadfile_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" accept-charset="utf-8" >
            <?php wp_nonce_field('name_of_my_action', 'wpnf_ft'); ?>
            <p><?php echo __('Select file to upload') ?><input type="file" name="uploadfiles[]" id="uploadfiles" size="35" class="uploadfiles" /><p>
                <input class="button-primary" type="submit" name="uploadfile_btn" id="uploadfile_btn" value="<?php echo __('Upload & Process') ?>"  />
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
        });
      });
      </script>
    <?php
}
```